# What is a "current load" on a 24 V input used for?

Tags: input, io, industrial

The [MAX14821](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/products/analog/sensors-and-sensor-interface/MAX14821.html) ([datasheet](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX14821.pdf)) is a 24 V IO device that features `selectable current loads for use in actuators` on the inputs.

What would this be used for? It's not just to load a 24 V "high" signal coming from a PNP-logic output, i.e. pull the input down of there's no signal? If it were, where's the equivalent high side current source for use with NPN signals?

Comment: There are signalling systems where the current is the signal, not the voltage.

Comment: Yes, usually the analog 0/4...20 mA [current loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current_loop#Process_control_4.E2.80.9320_mA_loops). But I could not find a concrete example yet for an approx. 7 mA constant current sink. Could this be to power "high-side" two-wire sensors (though contradicting the description)?

Comment: `Optional 6mA/7mA Current Loads at Both 24V Inputs`  is the selection

Answer (score 1):

Their reasoning:

> The C/Q and DI inputs have selectable current sinks that can be
>   enabled for use in actuators where the master requires a Type 2 load.

What is a Type 2 load?

I'm not so sure on this one, but the hint I found was on the [Pepperl and Fuchs page](https://www.pepperl-fuchs.com/usa/en/classid_202.htm?view=productdetails&prodid=34400):

> Switching point   according to DIN EN 61131-2 (Type 2)
>
> 0 (unattenuated)  ≤ 3 mA
>
> 1 (attenuated)    ≥ 5 mA

I don't have access to the DIN EN 61131-2, so I cannot give a more detailed explanation. Seems like there is a digital input standard related to current and 7 mA seems like a safe number to make something go high.

Answer (score 0):

PLC Standards Compliance Ensures Future-Proof Solutions
 ( two slightly different stds )

```
IO-Link Versions 1.0 and 1.1.2
IEC IEC61131.9 SDCI
```

---

Selectable means USA or EU stds for C/Q IO interfaces.  (clk & data high voltage long wire bus standards)

`Optional 6mA/7mA Current Loads at Both 24V Inputs is the selection`

For use with hi-side logic in 500m communication buswire pairs up to 400Kbaud ??

ie. 4k load to ground from 24V/4k = 6mA
e.g. IEC 61131 Type 1 uses 7mA with noise margins that @Arsenal pointed out for Type 2

[image]

Ref: IO-Link is the first standardised IO technology worldwide (IEC 61131-9) for the communication with sensors and also actuators.  http://io-link.com/share/Downloads/At-a-glance/IO-Link_System_Description_engl_2013.pdf

**A logic "1" is defined by the received voltage from a defined current in a selected load resistor to ground.**  If IO link is 6mA * 4k =24V then  IEC611131.9 is 7mA * ?? ....  and the thresholds are used for noise margins.

If you search hard enough you can read all the IEC standards free.

http://www.plcopen.org/pages/tc1_standards/  what each dash number means